# update panel in master page within asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a master page which contains an `Update Panel`

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="container" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Content" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In a child view I'd like when i click into a button to redirect to another view but just updating the content of the `container panel`

```
 protected void Login2_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Response.Redirect("/Candidat/Recap.aspx");
                UpdatePanel pan = (UpdatePanel)Master.FindControl("container");
                pan.Update();
          }
```

But it didn't work: the whole page is refreshed . So :

- What is the error i commited?
- How can i fix my code?

Comment: Response.Redirect won't work for this situation. It will redirect you to a new page, whether it's the current page or not.

Comment: So how can change the page and refresh just the part inside the panel ( the two pages inherits from the same master page)

Comment: There are several different ways you can achieve what you wanting to do. You can take a look at iFrames, which "embed" a web page within a page. However, I have no experience with these so you will have to look into it yourself. You could also use `<asp:Panel>` visibility property, and have a panel in the page with your "sub-page" content. Then just show or hide it depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a ScriptManager control on the page above the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: I put it in the master page